# Using multiple except blocks when catching an expression

Tags: python

I'm currently facing an issue in Python with try/except blocks.
Imagine the following case:

```py
class ExceptionA(Exception):
    pass

class ExceptionB(ExceptionA):
    pass

try:
    raise B()
except B:
    handle_B()
    handle_A()
    handle_default()
except A:
    handle_A()
    handle_default()
except Exception:
    handle_default()
```

In this example, there is a lot of code duplication and I would like a simpler way to handle this.

Currently, the best way I found is using `isinstance`, but it "destroys" the patern matching provided by except:

```py
try:
    raise B()
except Exception as exc:
    if isinstance(exc, Exception B) handle_B()
    if isinstance(exc, Exception A) handle_A()
    handle_default()
```

Any idea?

Comment: why would you call `handle_A` if you caught a `B`?

Comment: Shouldn't `except B` be `except ExceptionB`?

Comment: @Kurt I think that's the point -- there's some common handling for both A and B, he wants to know how to avoid the duplication.

Comment: It looks like there's some hierarchical relationship -- each exception adds some additional handling required. But there's no way to express that relationship in `try`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like a consistent way of doing this is to have a registry of all the local handler functions for each exception, and then a helper function to call then in order, according to inheritance rules - since we have two points where we want to access that registry: when adding specific handlers to exceptions, and upon calling the handlers, it seens apropriate to have a class for that.

The design could be further improved so that handlers are enabled or not depending on the section of the main project they are triggered.

(The `__mro__`  attribute in classes used bellow is dynamically maintained by Python to reflect the linearized inheritance for a class, so we get each ancestor class is checked in order for free)

```
class ExceptionHandlerRegistry:  # feel free for a shorter name
    def __init__(self):
        self.registry = {} 
        
    def register(self, exception, handler_callback):
        # if just one handler for exception is needed,
        # just access self.registry  directly as a dictionary
        self.registry.setdefault(exception, []).append(handler_callback)
        
    def handle(self, exception):
        for cls in type(exception).__mro__:
            for handler in self.registry.get(cls, ()):
                handler(exception)


e_handlers = ExceptionHandlerRegistry()
e_handler.register(ExceptionB, handle_B)
e_handler.register(ExceptionA, handle_A)
e_handler.register(Exception, handle_default)

class ExceptionA(Exception):
    pass

class ExceptionB(ExceptionA):
    pass


# And now the extensive, repeating pattern is reduced to:
try:
    raise ExceptionB()
except Exception as err:
    e_handlers.handle(err)
```

This aproach has the advantage of being easily modifiable - for example, it could look for handlers in each exception class itself, like in @Plagon's answer, that would not need to be explicitly registered.(Just add a `if "handler" in cls.__dict__: cls.handler(exception)` line in the first (`cls`) loop), or, as stated earlier, further conditions to control whether handlers are enabled or not -

And it can go as far as using some introspection in the handlers to inject arguments from the context where the exception took place (for example, if a handler callback has a `self`  argument, it could be fed the `self` variable automatically by the `.handle` method)

Otherwise, if you don't want to over-enginner, all you need is a dictionary and the three lines in the `.handle`  function to get what you are asking for.

Answer (score 3):

If possible, you could have `handle_B` call `handle_A` and `handle_A` call `handle_default`. Then the try-except would become:

```
try:
    ...
except ExceptionB:
    handle_B()
except ExceptionA:
    handle_A()
except Exception:
    handle_default()
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is through inheritance:

```
class BaseException(Exception):
    def handle(self):
        print('handle default')

class ExceptionA(BaseException):
    def handle(self):
        super().handle()
        print('handle A')

class ExceptionB(ExceptionA):
    def handle(self):
        super().handle()
        print('handle B')


try:
    raise ExceptionB()
except BaseException as e:
    e.handle()
```

Prints:

```
handle default
handle A
handle B
```

Comment: OP's code also handles `Exception`. How would you do that, with monkey-patching? Or a standalone function? I think standalone functions make more sense overall, cause it's not the job of an exception to know how to handle itself. Like, in one context you might want to issue a warning, but in another you might want to crash the program. I posted [my own answer using that](/a/76585210/4518341).

Comment: [`BaseException`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException) is a builtin, so you should use a different name

Comment: This approach is great. Not complete - but by pigbacking on the Exception inheritance itself, and using super, gets more than half things done.
but there is the semantic problem of an  ΅exception should not handle itself", complicated by the very practical problem that the handling code not being the same in different points where each exception occurs, and that one can't just stuff new methods into existing exceptions. But this is a start. Keeping a parallel registry of handlers that mimic the inheritance tree would be more correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested `try/except`, where the nested `except` blocks raise the next exception in the chain.

```
try:
    try:
        try:
            raise ExceptionB()
        except ExceptionB:
            handle_B()
            raise ExceptionA()
    except ExceptionA as e:
            handle_A()
            raise Exception()
except Exception:
    handle_default()
```